# CSS for dynamic form labels width

Tags: html, css, webforms, stylesheet

I'm currently working on refactoring one of our Form Controller so that we can use it for a public facing site.  Currently it's generating a table layout for the forms, but I am trying to get it done using CSS forms.

I am trying to reproduce something that would look like this http://www.stylephreak.com/uploads/source/cssforms/cssform.php

Issue I am having is that every CSS form examples I find seems to assume a fixed width for the left column label.  I have no control over what goes in the label in my case, it's coming from a user editable translation bank.  With a table it's super easy I would simply use whitespace:nowrap; and the longest label would decide on the td's width and everyone is happy.

Is it possible to do something similar with CSS? I've tried using min-width and forcing it not to wrap.  This worked but only pushes the current control right and screwed up the alignment, not to mention that min-width isn't supported in IE 6.

Is it really that bad to use a table for form layouts? It's tabular data and make sense when linearized after all no?

Comment: `max-width` instead of `min-width`?

Comment: @Stijntjhe max-width wouldn't work in my case I think. I do want them to align so I need some sort of width.  If I only specify max-width for my labels they will be all over the place no?

Comment: If I add a margin-bottom:0.6em at the label at least it doesn't look horrible when it wrap (it used to get to close to the other control since it's floating left)

Comment: I thought you used `min-width` but you should use `max-width`.
The question is a little bit confusing.

Comment: You really shouldn't be concerned about IE6 any longer.

Comment: I think you're better off setting a fixed width than using a table for non-tabular information.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can set the `<label>` css to `display: table-cell` and the containing `<div>` to `display: table-row`.  This will mimic the behavior of using a table without actually using a `<table>`.

```
<div style="display: table-row">
    <label style="display: table-cell; padding: 0 1em; text-align: right;" for="fm-firstname">First Name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="fm-firstname" id="fm-firstname" />
</div>
<div style="display: table-row">
    <label style="display: table-cell; padding: 0 1em; text-align: right;" for="fm-lastname">Last:</label>
    <input type="text" name="fm-lastname" id="fm-lastname" />
</div>
```

This will look great in any recent browser (Firefox, Chrome, IE8+).  In IE7, the textboxes won't be aligned correctly.

Comment: Neat solution, but not working in IE 6 could pass, but not supporting IE 7 I don`t think that will fly with upper management ;)

Comment: I checked analytics, unfortunately IE 7 still accounts for 20% of our visitors... why won't people just upgrade!

Comment: +1 and accepted, this is the good solution hopefully the browsers will catch up to CSS specs soon.  Thanks NGLN for the other answers as well +1.

Answer (score 2):

Well, here's a solution that is a bit unconventional, but I think the simplicity should work for all browsers.

[The sample fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NGLN/e3Qfs/).

Accessibility doesn't seem to be a problem, for both keyboard and mouse control act as whished. The main disadvantage of course is that this page does not render well if CSS is turned off. Are there somewhere statistics about that? And also don't I know how screen readers will react to this wantonness.

Comment: Simple fix, but I feel that "a bit unconventional" is an understatement.

Comment: Not sure how fiddle rendered that properly but it doesn't work in FireFox or Chrome.  http://pastebin.com/GjcQwRRj

Comment: @jfrobishow: You have to add a valid doctype declaration. In quirks mode it does get ugly indeed. That's how quirks' supposed to be.

Answer (score 1):

To my knowlegde `form`s always occupy 100% of the available width. You could use that.

If it's allowed to fill up the whole width of the provided container for this form, then this seems a valid answer:

[The sample fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/NGLN/m5szk/3/)

The minor disadvantage in this case is to choose the ratio between the width of the labels and the inputs.