# Form markup; getting a line break after a label when using display: table-cell, table-row

Tags: html, css

Please refer to [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pVHLY/).

My objective is to conceive of some HTML markup that will allow me to auto-generate forms with variable label widths, labels on top or left without having to conditionally generate [much] markup.

To achieve label alignment with varied label widths, I am using a `display: table cell/row;` trick as listed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6153733/css-for-dynamic-form-labels-width).

However, this will only work when all my labels are `label.left.` When I have a `label.top`, I cannot figure out a CSS way to push the sibling `div.control` to the next line!

Can anybody imagine a simple approach to doing this, or a better suited layout to achieve what I am looking for?

Just so I am completely clear, I wish the `div.control` for 'Last Name' to appear on the next line from its label.

Thank you!

Comment: Is it necessary to use table-row?

Comment: No, it is not. So far, apart from using tables, it is the only way I have figured out to allow for automatic label width alignment. If you have an alternative I am all ears!

Comment: you just tell me what exactly layout and structure you want i will give you the solution immediately. if possible show image or screen shot.

Comment: Hey you follow this link: http://www.stylephreak.com/uploads/source/cssforms/cssform.php

Comment: As in my original post, my requirements are that labels are automatically aligned, regardless of their width. Labels may be on top or on the left, as indicated by the .top and .left classes. 

If you visit the jsfiddle I linked, imagine that the input field for  'last name' is on an new line.

This is trivial to do by hand. I need to automatically generate this markup, which is why I would like a CSS based solution.

Comment: see answer and let me know if any issues or corrections.

Answer (score 0):

If  i am understanding your problem and comments this might be you want or if not clarify me so i can give you the exact solution.

See the fiddle for code and demo

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pVHLY/1/

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/pVHLY/1/embedded/result/